# Scroll Div to specific place

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a 12 month calendar in a scollable div, so that one can see two calendar-months at a time. Beside it is a weekly planner.

[image]

---

<sup>*Click on image for bigger picture.*</sup>

In top menu of the page user can change week being displayed. These are links with week number and year as parameters.

What I need is that when a user navigate to a week, the left div scrolls to the corresponding month. How can I achieve this?

[Link to test page.](http://logicalwebhost.com/goats/calendar/test.php)

Comment: There's a parameter in your url as "wk" which you could use to determine which week you are on and calculate the month bumber accordingly, then you can apply an offset top to the calendar table to scroll to your month accordingly, hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: @Pieter Can you use jQuery, and is a jQuery-based solution acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this algorithm. You have to find the month to go.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Write this code under click event. and set goto variable assign here
    var goto="Feb";
    $('#calendar_container').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+ goto).offset().top},400 );
});
```

You need to define IDs for each months of the calender
Ex:

- January calender ID is "Jan"
- February calender ID is "Feb"

  like.

Then set goto variable Equuleus to your ID

Answer (score 0):

Hrmf. Did not know you had linked in site and only discovered it by chance when looking at edit done to your question. Also missed out on the fact that weeks only got changed by clicking menu on top. But, anyhow, here is an update:

---

Given your markup and link logic + the fact that you are using jQuery one suggestion would be:

1. Add `id` for each calendar month.
2. On DOM ready, (document loaded), check URL week / year and calculate month.
3. Find calendar by `id`.
4. Set `scrollTop` for div wrap holding calendar.

***1.)*** ID's has to be unique. In your markup all month tables have `id="example"`. Change this to for example:

```
id="cal_month_01"
id="cal_month_02"
id="cal_month_03"
...
```

***2., 3., 4.)*** Get date from URL and do the scroll:

```
// Get date from year / week.
function week2date(y, w, isoSunday) {
    var d = new Date(y, 0, 1 + (w - 1) * 7);
    if (isoSunday) {
        d.setDate(
            d.getDay() < 5 ?
            d.getDate() - d.getDay() :
            d.getDate() + 7 - d.getDay()
        );
    }
    return d;
}

function scrollMonth() {
    // Get year and week from URL-(window)-location.
    var year = window.location.href.match(/\byr=(\d{4})\b/);
    var week = window.location.href.match(/\bwk=(\d+)\b/);
    if (week && year) {
        // Get month from year / week.
        // Months start at 0 in JavaScript
        var date = week2date(year[1], week[1], true).getMonth() + 1;
        // Make ID, zero pad month.
        var id = 'cal_month_' + ('0' + month).substr(-2);
        var $cal = $('#mini_Calendar');
        // Do the scroll.
        // Note that you need to subtract offset top for container.
        $cal.animate({
            scrollTop: $('#' + id).offset().top - $cal.offset().top
        }, 200);
    }
}

// Execute when document ready.
$(document).ready(scrollMonth);
```

---

Other tips:

Use validation service on your markup and CSS. This is going to save you a lot of headache. (And perhaps also introduce some ;).

- [HTML validation](http://validator.w3.org)
- [CSS validation](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

---

#### Old answer:

---

You can use `scrollTop` in combination with `offsetTop` to set scroll for the months container.

»» ***[Very crude demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/XyTqj/)*** ««

It all depends a lot on your markup and how you actually generate the document.

You would likely add an event listener for the week-container, get week/date or what ever and scroll to corresponding month.

One layout which should be adaptable is using `data-*` attributes and something like this:

```
<div id="calendar">
   <div data-month="1">Januar 1, 2, 3, ...</div>
   <div data-month="2">Februar 1, 2, 3, ...</div>
   ...
</div>
```

This for weeks:

```
<div id="week">
   <ul>
       <li data-date="2013.1.1">1</li>
       <li data-date="2013.1.2">2</li>
       <li data-date="2013.1.3">3</li>
       ...
</div>
```

To scroll one could then do:

```
function target(e) {
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (t.nodeType === 3) 
        t = t.parentNode;
    return t;
}
function scrollCalendar(e) {
    function scroll(e) {
        e.parentElement.scrollTop = e.offsetTop - 5;
    }
    e = e || window.event;
    var t = target(e), 
        date = t['data-date'], 
        cal, cal_m, sel_m, i;
    if (date) {
        // Calendar container
        cal   = document.getElementById('calendar');
        // One div for each month.
        cal_m = cal.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
        // Date from week-view 
        date  = date.split('.');
        sel_m = +date[1];
        for (i = 0; i < cal_m.length; ++i) {
            // Check if month equals to clicked date.
            if (+cal_m[i]['data-month'] === sel_m) {
                scroll(cal_m[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Calculate your height with some algorithm , which would be easy like (total height )*(slNo of specificweek)/(number of weeks) , like that , i have implemented simmilar thing and thats how i did it , which was convenient for me like this

use scrollTop in jquery
add something like this

```
      $("#Div").animate({ scrollTop: 500)}, 1000)// replace500- your height


     ("#Div")[0].scrollHeight) // this will give you total height of scrollable area
```

Comment: the first paragraph is unclear, and your suggested code is a bad approach: there are ways to automatically calculate the proper scrolling position based on the location of each calendar element, and attempting to hardcode the values would have bad results in any browser that chose to display it slightly differently